# C# OPC-DA disconnect from server

Tags: c#, opc, opc-da

Hi I have following code to connect to the OPC server, which is working fine.

```
server = new Opc.Da.Server(fact, null);
server.Url = new Opc.URL(URL);
server.Connect();
```

Now when I use following code to disconnect from the server my code get stucks, I assume it is waiting for the disconnect, but it seems like this is never happening.

```
server.Disconnect();
```

For this I used the opc.da library from OPCFoundation.

Comment: Are you sure a connection has been established in the first place?

Comment: Deadlock is not unusual, use the Debug > Windows > Threads window to find out what is going on.  You'll want to verify that the thread that created the "server" object is not hung up on doing something else and that no thread is busy handling an event.